# dhcp no lease because of not-DAD mode

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, dhcp, arp

My virtual machine does not receive an IP lease anymore.

Manually requesting a new ip lease by '`ifdown/ifup eth0`' or '`dhclient eth0`' or '`service network restart`' don't work either.

The error is always the same:

```
Determining IP information for eth0...arping: no source address in not-DAD mode done.
```

My next step was deleting the udev rule: 70-persistent-net.rules from /etc/udev/rules.d and stop-starting the virtual machine.

It has worked fine in this virtual machine, the VLAN interface etc have not been changed.

for info, the configuration of the interface:

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
```

I have removed the mac and uuid entries from the file before deleting the udev rulesdefinition for network.